# TypeScript: Put array into array

Tags: typescript

Note: This question is about **TypeScript** (not JavaScript).

I want to put an array into an array at a specified position:

```
var a = [];
a[0] = [1,2];
```

`a` is now `[1,2]` but should be `[[1,2]]`.

How can I achieve that my array `[1,2]` that I want to put into the array is not flattened but put directly as it is into the array?
so finally i need the procedure for putting array into array .

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between TypeScript and JavaScript here. There could not be, or TypeScript would no longer be a strict superset of JavaScript.

Comment: As noted your code is giving an array of arrays. Also worth mentioning that directly adding to position `n` in an array that hasn't been initialized is a bad idea for performance

Comment: This works "as is" in TypeScript - demo on the TypeScript playground: http://bit.ly/1znxNqh

Comment: @basarat it is slow as in "only 59,000,000 operations per second" - so you'd have be nested in a loop of loops to notice any performance issue (the performance is also the other way around in IE) :) - http://jsperf.com/adding-to-an-array-directly

Comment: @SteveFenton you are right it doesn't matter : http://jsperf.com/adding-to-an-array-directly/2 It is potentially *twice* as fast but I thought the order of magnitude was much larger (something like stringbuilder vs. string kind of difference). And IE is equally slow on both ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you are right. The code in my question works as expected.

I was just confused by visual studio debugger visualizer:

[image]

...showing `[[1,2]]` as `[1,2]` (which is really not nice, is it?).

And also confused by internet explorer 11 console:

[image]

...showing `[[1,2]]` as `1,2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet

```
a = new Array(5)

a[0] = new Array(2)

a[0][0] = Array(1,2);

a[0][1] = Array(3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you seeing a as [1,2]? I just tried this and it shows [[1,2]]

Also, a different method you could try is to use push:

a.push([1,2]);

both the push() and your code give me the same results, both are what you are looking for. Are you seeing this in a browser? or node?

Comment: Did you try it in TypeScript? I need the functionality in TypeScript not in JavaScript.

Comment: I just tried here and same thing, it is giving the correct result: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0Aa.push(%5B1%2C2%5D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(a)%3B

Comment: You are right it works. I was confused by visual studio debugger (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:
I tried what you said in console and I get the expected result:

```
a = []

a[0] = [1,2]

a; output=>
[Array[2]]

a.length: output=>
1

a[0].length: output=>
2
```

Comment: I know that it works in JavaScript, that's why I am surprised that it does not work the same in TypeScript. I need the functionality in TypeScript not in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine

```js
var a = [];
a[0] = [1, 2];
console.log(a.join(',')); //prints, `1,2`
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); //prints, `[[1,2]]`
```

```html
Open console...
```